# html5 offline application on multiple platform

Tags: html, offline-caching, offlineapps, offline-browsing

I want to develop a offline web app which will work on multiple platform(PC,Android). This is a basically a product display web app so that each product will have image,video,details of product etc. For development of this web app HTML5 is the choice. I will copy web app files to each device so that I could run it offline. But here I need a back-end so that I could delete outdated product and add new products(which will have details,image,video). Is there anyway so that I could add/delete product from one device and copy these files to all other devices.

I have come across HTML Appcache, using this i can build normal php site and using manifest i can store it in browser appcache for offline viewing. But this requires internet connection in each device and access the web app through browser.

I would like to know if there is any other way I could do this without keeping files in web server.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is probably what you're looking for ([Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/))

Also be aware that app store policies may end up dooming your app if it doesn't look and feel native. Expect Apple to be very strict about this.

Comment: For Mac OS X there is Sentenza Desktop, available on CodeCanyon.net.

Comment: @alexk Thanks. But PhoneGap app wont be able to run on PC's.

Comment: @sumaise According to PhoneGap, you can create a Windows Store app (Windows 8/RT). Perhaps that helps, maybe not: [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html) See my edited answer as well.

Comment: @sumaise (I actually ended up not editing my original answer.) With your project requirements, it seems rather strange that you insist on it being offline. It needs to be cross-platform, updated often, and it's a product catalog. Not to dismiss your question or anything, but it seems like this project _should_ be an online web site.

Also, have you been designing this with an offline database for your catalog, like SQLite? Then you could make simple apps (perhaps relying on HTML5) and just update the database file when you need to update your products without having to code anything else.